# awk/sed/perl one liner + how to print only the properties lines from json file

Tags: awk, sed, perl, json, jq

how to print only the properties lines from json file

**example of json file**

```
{
  "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
      "tag" : "version1527250007610",
      "type" : "kafka-env",
      "version" : 8,
      "Config" : {
        "cluster_name" : "HDP",
        "stack_id" : "HDP-2.6"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi",
        "is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
        "kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
        "kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
        "kafka_user" : "kafka",
        "kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
        "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
      }
    }
  ]
```

**expected output**

```
    "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi",
    "is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
    "kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
    "kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
    "kafka_user" : "kafka",
    "kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
    "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
```

Comment: Related question on SO: [Parsing 
 JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**`Jq`** is the right tool for processing JSON data:

```
jq '.items[].properties | to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value)"' input.json
```

The output:

```
"content : \n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi"
"is_supported_kafka_ranger : true"
"kafka_log_dir : /var/log/kafka"
"kafka_pid_dir : /var/run/kafka"
"kafka_user : kafka"
"kafka_user_nofile_limit : 128000"
"kafka_user_nproc_limit : 65536"
```

---

In case if it's really mandatory to obtain each key and value double-quoted - use the following modification:

```
jq -r '.items[].properties | to_entries[]
       | "\"\(.key)\" : \"\(.value | gsub("\n";"\\n"))\","' input.json
```

The output:

```
"content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e "/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi",
"is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
"kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
"kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
"kafka_user" : "kafka",
"kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
"kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536",
```

Comment: You advocate using a syntax-aware tool (`jq`) rather than naive string operations, which is good, but then you use a naive string operation to do (limited) escape sequence processing for output. That doesn't seem like a good idea to me. `jq` must have a way to properly escape  the value for output, right?

Comment: @DanielPryden, No. Although *`jq` does have some ways to properly escape the value for output* (like `@text`, `@sh` etc), those won't help in this particular case.

Comment: A variant that leaves the properties values as JSON objects and uses sed to strip the unwanted braces and whitespace:
`jq '.items[].properties' input.json | sed -n 's/^\s\+//p'`

Comment: why "," isn't appears in the output , as my expected results ?

Comment: can you see please my "expected output" , can you edit your answer according to my expected results ?

Comment: @yael, what do mean exactly?

Comment: in your output I see missing comma separator "," in the end of line , you can see my expected output in my question that comma separator must be in the end of each line

Comment: @yael, just add comma before the last double quote, see my update (although the last line will also have a trailing comma)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I see another problem with jq -r '.items[].properties | to_entries[]
       | "\"\(.key)\" : \"\(.value | gsub("\n";"\\n"))\","' input.json

Comment: its removed the backslash before the double quote , for example if we have in the file \"  , then its remove the "\" ,

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  , if you want I can ask this question "above" with another thread ?

Comment: @yael, yes, instead of continuously extending and augmenting the input content you can initiate a new question with new conditions

Comment: ok thank you I will , few min I will sent it

Comment: I published the thread on a new question

Answer (score 28):

Please, please don’t get into the habit of parsing structured data with unstructured tools. If you’re parsing XML, JSON, YAML etc., use a specific parser, at least to convert the structured data into a more appropriate form for AWK, `sed`, `grep` etc.

In this case, [`gron`](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) would help greatly:

```
$ gron yourfile | grep -F .properties.
json.items[0].properties.content = "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:/home/steve/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi";
json.items[0].properties.is_supported_kafka_ranger = "true";
json.items[0].properties.kafka_log_dir = "/var/log/kafka";
json.items[0].properties.kafka_pid_dir = "/var/run/kafka";
json.items[0].properties.kafka_user = "kafka";
json.items[0].properties.kafka_user_nofile_limit = "128000";
json.items[0].properties.kafka_user_nproc_limit = "65536";
```

(You can post-process this with `| cut -d. -f4- | gron --ungron` to get something very close to your desired output, albeit still as valid JSON.)

[`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) is [also appropriate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446333/86440).

Answer (score 1):

From [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a):

```
sed -n '/properties/,/}$/ {
            /properties/n
            /}$/ !p
        }' FILE.json
```

For a more exact match and to also take care of closing bracket lines with additional whitespace you can use

```
sed -E -n '/"properties" : {/,/^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]$/ {
               /"properties" : {/n
               /^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]$/ !p
           }' FILE.json
```

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON but maybe `/}/` is safer than `/}$`. The latter seems not to have any advantages anyway.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Without the end-of-line marker it already matches the `content` line which contains a `}` somewhere.

Comment: Even though it is possible, it will most likely only work on the *example* file. If you want to parse structured data, you should rather use something designed for that. Be it jq, xpath, yq, xq, etc. That's because parsing it with line-oriented tools will eventually bite you in the back and debugging that might not be very easy.

Comment: For example, what happens if one of the 'href' fields contains the word "properties"?

Comment: @StigHemmer That's why I extended the pattern in the second example. But I totally agree that using `gron` or `jq` is the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` one liner.  Print lines between regular expression `properties` (i.e line containing "properties") and regular expression `^ *}` (i.e. line starting with zero or more spaces followed by "}" and end-of-line).

```
sed -n '/properties/,/^ *}$/{//!p}' file.json
```

`awk` one liner.

```
awk '/^ *}/{s=0}/properties/{getline;s=1}s' file.json
```

Comment: maybe you could explain how does your pattern matching works.

Comment: While this works for the example file given, it is risky trying to parse JSON with tools that doesn't understand it.  For example, what happens if one of the 'href' fields contains the word "properties"? It is far less bug-prone to a JSON-aware tool like the top-voted answers.

Comment: Agree, risky.  But OP specifically wanted a one-liner solution using sed/awk/perl.  The answer I've given meet all these criteria.

Comment: What does `//!p` mean? Print if not one of the things that matched?

Comment: Ah, got it, `//` repeats the last regex, `!` not, `p` print. NIce.

Answer (score 1):

It's tagged `perl`, and I see no `perl` answer yet, so I'll chip in.

Don't use regular expressions or other 'unstructured' parsers. `perl` has the `JSON` module with it. (`JSON::PP` is part of the core since 5.14 too)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $json = decode_json ( $str );

my $properties = $json -> {items} -> [0] -> {properties}; 

#dump the whole lot:
print Dumper $properties;


# or iterate
foreach my $key ( sort keys %$properties ) { 
   print "$key => ", $properties -> {$key},"\n";
}


__DATA__
{
  "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://master02:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configurations?type=kafka-env&tag=version1527250007610",
      "tag" : "version1527250007610",
      "type" : "kafka-env",
      "version" : 8,
      "Config" : {
        "cluster_name" : "HDP",
        "stack_id" : "HDP-2.6"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}\nexport PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\nexport PID_DIR={{kafka_pid_dir}}\nexport LOG_DIR={{kafka_log_dir}}\nexport KAFKA_KERBEROS_PARAMS={{kafka_kerberos_params}}\nexport JMX_PORT=9997\n# Add kafka sink to classpath and related depenencies\nif [ -e \"/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\" ]; then\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink.jar\n  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/lib/*\nfi\n\nif [ -f /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh ]; then\n. /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-ranger-env.sh\nfi",
        "is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
        "kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
        "kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
        "kafka_user" : "kafka",
        "kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
        "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Naturally you'd read from `STDIN` or a filename rather than `DATA` in your real usage scenario.